# ! Use of doesn't match its definition. l.10 Error

Tags: errors

I was working on this thesis template which was compiling fine until I used a `\verb` command in my code. From then code is showing countless errors like the one given below:-

```
! Use of doesn't match its definition.
l.10 ...sageBreak This may be a bug in a package f
ile you are using\par } {\...
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.
```

I commented all the code that I wrote on that day before error popped up, but still same errors.

I don't even know which part of the code is the problem so don't know what to paste here.

This is the code that I wrote after which errors appeared:

```
\begin{figure}[h]

\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{TAMUthesis_AddChapter.png}
\caption{Add More Chapters Into TAMUthesis\_Template.tex.
[For example, a new chapter named "myNewChapterName.tex" is created under the
folder of data. To put this new file for the compilation by adding the line \verb+\eqref{}+ char as shown in 281 (uncomment the  in front.)]}
```

Below is the link to access the files

https://www.mediafire.com/?7l9ieny56v8sp0e

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You mention `\verb`: how are you using it?

Comment: I had to display Latex commands such that they are not compiled but displayed as text. So I used \verb+\eqref{}... And i used this is command at a couple of places.. But now all of that is commented.. but still errors are there

Comment: It's quite difficult to help you with so little information; a minimal example producing the error is necessary for a diagnosis.

Comment: @ShraySharan: Did you close the `\verb+....` with a `+` then too?

Comment: Christian Hupfer: Yes I did

Comment: @egreg this is the code that I wrote after which the code started throwing errors:-   \begin{figure}[h]

\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.75]{TAMUthesis_AddChapter.png}
\caption{Add More Chapters Into TAMUthesis\_Template.tex.
[For example, a new chapter named "myNewChapterName.tex" is created under the
folder of data. To put this new file for the compilation by adding the line \verb+\eqref{}+

char as shown in 281 
(uncomment the  in front.)]}

Comment: I have edited the post  and  added the code which according to me created the problems

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You can't use `\verb` in the argument to `\caption`.

Comment: Don't use `\verb` in the arguments of other commands, and delete the .lof-file to get rid of the errors.

Comment: But why is it still showing errors after I commented everything

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I will remove the verb command... But I did'nt understand what you mentioned about the .lof-file.. Which file is this? How can I delete this?

Comment: It's  a file with the ending .lof in your document folder. It contains the text of the captions for the list of figures.

Comment: The error message you show is not the format TeX uses.  please show the exact error lines from the log file.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer Those errors are gone.... Thank you so much and everyone who shared their thoughts.. I am still left with 4 errors which are ! Missing \endcsname inserted, ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} and ! Extra \endcsname..

Comment: I do have a begin document in my code but still the error is there

Comment: @ShraySharan: Sounds like you have code that tries to typeset text etc. in the preamble, i.e. before `\begin{document}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have just 1 command before the begin document and that is \documentclass[SectionMethod, ListStyleI]{TAMUthesis}. I am trying to share the code with you via media fire

Answer (score 2):

As already I wrote answering to the [crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=26485) on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum):

You cannot use \verb within `\caption`, as egreg and Ulrike said in the comments her before. `\verb` is very specific, as it doesn't interpret LaTeX commands in its argument. So you cannot use it within macros.

It's even more unusable in a moving argument, that means it's written into a file. Captions are written into a file, to be loaded and interpreted in the next LaTeX compiler run.

It can already be fixed by simply using typewriter font with a backslash in front. The output will be as desired.

Note, you should delete the external file where it was written to. In this case, it can be the `.lof` file which contains the captions for the list of figures, so also the illegal `\verb` command, so remove it. It will be re-generated in the next run, re-read to be interpreted one run later.